# How to connect two subscriptions in RXJava/Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, rx-java, rx-android

How can I bind two subscriptions like:

1) Retrofit&RX which converts JSON into list of strings shown in recyclerView.

```
    restClient.getCatFacts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<CatFactsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onError, " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(CatFactsResponse catFactsResponse) {
                    catFactsList = catFactsResponse.getCatFacts();
                }
            });
```

2) And Jack Wharton's RxBinding library to react to changes made in EditText widget.

```
subscription = RxTextView
            .textChangeEvents(editText)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onError >> " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {
                    Log.i(TAG, textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString());
                }
            });
```

to get list which is dynamically filtered using EditText. Am I supposed to use classes like Subject or sth? If yes, then how should it look like? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `flatMap` operator

```
    subscription = RxTextView
            .textChangeEvents(editText)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(new Func1<TextViewTextChangeEvent, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {
                    return textViewTextChangeEvent.text();
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<CatFactsResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<CatFactsResponse> call(String text) {
                    return restClient.getCatFacts(text)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                }
            })
            .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Now I finally know how can I make such relations :)